# Security as a service for REST services

Tags: web-services, rest

I am implementing RESTful web services using NetBeans (JAX-RS) and Glassfish server to expose database resources.

I want to implement varying levels of security depending upon the users requirement (maybe choice provided to user). From various discussions regarding REST security, I understand there are different ways (given below) in which security can be implemented. How can I implement a security solution as a service which will be invoked depending upon the context.

TLS (HTTPS) +
1.  HTTP Basic 
2.  HTTP Digest
3.  two-legged OAuth
4.  a Cookie-based approach
5.  client certificates 
6.  Signed requests using HMAC and a limited lifetime

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement security by using **Policies at Runtime**.

Policy gives the flexibility to implement different security scenario (userauth, oauth,saml etc) depending upon the context.
**We implemented the same in  web service using Apache CXF and  WS-SecurityPolicy.**
For rest service I think similar concept can be used.